# Getting the return value from a function

Tags: php

Say I got some function that run some code and then `return` something, like this:

```
function something()
{
//some code
return $some[$whatever];
}
```

So, if I want to extract the data I generated in the function - the new value for `$some`, how should I do it? for example this won't do anything:

```
echo ($some);
```

Or what am I missing here, please

Comment: Just call the function and it will return the value?!

Comment: instead of `echo` use `print_r` because it seems your function returns array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Function` returns a value, You may need to catch & store it inside a `variable` and then echo the variable if it is a String or do some casting to that effect. Here's an example:

```
<?php
    function something(){
        //some code
        $whatever  = 3;
        $some      = ["Peace", "Amongst", "All", "Humanity"];
        return $some[$whatever];
    }

    $var = something();

    var_dump($var); //<== DUMPS :: "Humanity"
    echo $var;      //<== ECHOES:: "Humanity"
```

Test it out [here](https://eval.in/606298).

Cheers and Good Luck....

Comment: why do you think you need that extra variable?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath   Was only Following up on his code so that everything appears consistent with what he already thinks and posted... not more, but thank you for the down-vote, though. May You be filled and may your heart Grow as Large as the Sky to accommodate others lovingly .... and by the way he is only a beginner... as you can see.... ;-)

Comment: THANK YOU! Poiz! And yes, I'm a beginner :) You rock!

Comment: @domifrosle     Every Master was once a Student... The Master of Today who was but a lousy pupil Yesterday only had enough drive to keep at it till he mastered it... and so will you (or anyone else) till mastery takes the place of struggle. Thanks Mate.... For a beginner, you rock too!!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a specif key from your array, which wasn't declared. I declared an array for you, and I added the isset to check if the key is existing in the array to prevent any php warnings.

```
function something($findKey)
{
$some = array('key'=> 123);
if(!isset($some[$findKey])) {
    return false;
}
//some code
return $some[$findKey];
}
echo something('key');
```